# JNI - automatically attach all newly spawned threads from process to JVM?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, dll, java-native-interface

I call a dll from Java using JNI. The DLL calls another thirdparty library which spawns a bunch of threads and sends callbacks to my dll. I want these callbacks to be attached to the JVM. What is the best way to do this? I think since the threads call the callback method, the callbacks aren't attached to the JVM, so I have to attach it?

Is there no... inheritance, like all threads created by this thread will automatically attached to the JVM?

I've looked at the documentation but I can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually call `AttachCurrentThread()` (and `DetachCurrentThread()`) from each thread that needs to call into the VM. There is no automatic mechanism.

Comment: is there a way to check is the current thread is attached, like isAttached() or something?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: No, but it's perfectly safe attaching multiple times, and you just need one Detach even if you attached many times.

Comment: Do you know if it check internally if the thread is already attached or does it reattach it anyway? I'm just wondering if there's some performance hit

Comment: According to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html any extra attach is a noop.